Row Operations Preserving Total Unimodularity
I've been learning about linear programming recently and have come across totally unimodular matrices. I understand that row operations do not necessarily preserve total unimodularity, but I thought of a question that I've been struggling with.
Let $M$ be a $m \times n$ totally unimodular matrix. Suppose we perform row operations entirely contained within the first $k < m$ rows of $M$ so that the submatrix consisting of the first $k$ rows remains totally unimodular, and the submatrix consisting of the last $m-k$ rows is totally unimodular. Denote this new matrix as $M'$. Will $M'$ be totally unimodular?
